# JSON Schema - unique pattern properties

Tags: json, jsonschema

I want to create a JSON Schema that allows properties with names that are arbitrary, but unique.

I have been trying to do this with patternProperties, but it seems to allow duplicate property names.

For example, the following schema:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema",
    "type": "object",
    "patternProperties": {
                "^.*$": {
                    "type": "string"
                }
            },
            "additionalProperties": false
}
```

Validates this JSON:

```
{
  "property1" : "value1",
  "property2" : "value2",
  "property1" : "value3"
}
```

But I want it to fail because the 1st and 3rd property have the same name.  How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMHO...

JSON Schema doesn't have any validation to detect duplicate properties in a JSON object.

The JSON spec doesn't make any mention of duplicate properties so they are valid but not recommended.

to check on duplicated names:

```cs
void Main()
{
    try
    {
        JsonSchema schema = JsonSchema.Parse(@"{
  '$schema': 'https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema',
    'type': 'object',
    'patternProperties': {
                '^.*$': {
                    'type': 'string'
                }
            },
            'additionalProperties': false
    }");


        JObject o = JObject.Parse("{\"property1\":\"value1\",\"property2\":\"value2\",\"property1\":\"value3\"}", new JsonLoadSettings
        {
            DuplicatePropertyNameHandling = DuplicatePropertyNameHandling.Error
        });

        bool valid = o.IsValid(schema).Dump();
        // true
    }
    catch (JsonReaderException ex)
    {
        Console.Write($"Invalid json file, {ex.Message}.");
    }
}
```

the exception would be :

```
[Invalid json file, Property with the name 'property1' already exists in the current JSON object. Path 'property1', line 1, position 55..]
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a good solution.  Interestingly, if I don't add DuplicatePropertyNameHandling, it deserializes fine and just uses the last of the duplicates, discarding the earlier ones.

Answer (score 0):

> Short answer is yes.. but you have

I used this [uniqueItems](https://ajv.js.org/json-schema.html#uniqueitems) section to help answer your questions, https://ajv.js.org/json-schema.html#uniqueitems

1. use a 3rd party library called AJV https://ajv.js.org/ to create your own properties
2. Now you can create the unique schema and validate wit with that.

---

```
// you get the AJV sechma validator
// go here you will see it, https://ajv.js.org/
const Ajv = require('ajv');
const ajv = new Ajv(); // Instantiate Ajv JSON Schema validator

// Here I would create my custom or own JSON schema
const myUniqueSschema = {
  "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "items": {
      "type": "array",
      // this is what you should try, unique
      "uniqueItems": true 
    }
  }
};
```

---

make sure you install first

```
npm install -g ajv-cli
ajv compile -s schema.json -o validate_schema.js
```

---

you can either write a function or modify the data to do it for you
https://ajv.js.org/guide/modifying-data.html